# Jupyter-lab: go to previously active cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Does JupyterLab support a functionality to jump to previously selected or active cell?

Use case #1: sometimes I accidentally hit "Home" or "End" while in Command mode (thinking that I am in Editing mode) and I jump to the very top of my notebook. Then I need to find the place where I was doing the editing.

Use case #2: Sometimes its convenient to do the above on purpose. Jump to the bottom, run a side calculation and then come back to the previously active cell to continue my main line coding.

It would also be nice to assign a shortcut to this command if it exists. I've looked through this [github thread](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5371), but have not found an appropriate command.

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-go-to-definition. It allows to jump to a definition of a variable with `alt` + `click` and then jump back with `alt` + `o`. It may work for a subset of use case #2 and the code may be adapted to work with #1 and full #2 (I am considering doing so in free time, feel free to open issue/PR in the repo).